# Returning a variable from a rules action

Tags: nodes, rules, entities, actions

I am trying to create a variation on Fetch Entity, and I'm having trouble returning an entity. I'm just grabbing the data using db_query, and trying to return an array of nodes that are loaded, but that doesn't seem to be the data structure needed to allow me to publish them.

Basically I want to return an entity (which will always be a node in this case), and then publish it.

```
    'MY_MODULE_actions_pseudo_fetch' => array(
      'label' => t('Fetch entity by Project Request field'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'type' => array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'label' => t('Entity type'),
          'options list' => 'MY_MODULE_gen_node_list',
          'description' => t('Specifies the type of the entity that should be fetched.'),
          'restriction' => 'input',
        ),
        'value' => array(
          'type' => 'unknown',
          'label' => t('Value'),
          'description' => t('The property value of the entity to be fetched.'),
        ),
      ),
      'base' => 'MY_MODULE_actions_pseudo_fetch',
      'provides' => array(
        'entity_fetched' => array('type' => 'list', 'label' => t('Fetched entity')),
      ),
      'group' => t('Entities'),
    )


function MYMODULE_actions_pseudo_fetch($type, $value) {

  $nid = $value->nid;

  $results = db_query("select pr.entity_id from {field_data_field_project_req} pr where pr.field_project_req_target_id = :nid", array(':nid' => $nid));

  $node_array = array();
  foreach($results as $result) {
    $node_array[] = node_load($result->entity_id);
  }
    return $node_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a Rule action can provide multiple variables, an array should be returned providing the value(s) belonging to the keys defined in hook_rules_action_info() hook.

In your case your function `MYMODULE_actions_pseudo_fetch($type, $value)` should `return array('entity_fetched' => $node_array);`